# How can I go back to the previous ViewController from UICollectionViewCell?

Tags: swift

There are two pages(view controllers) in `Main.storyboard`: `FirstViewController` and `SecondViewController`. I have added a button into `FirstViewController`. Here is the button click scope:

```
    let controller = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainPage") as! SecondViewController
    controller.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    show(controller, sender: nil)
```

I have added `UICollectionView` into `SecondViewController`. `UICollectionViewCell` is also added (with .xib file) I have added back button in to .xib file. And I wanted to write below code for back button action(please focus func btnBack)

```
import UIKit

class ViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var lblOutlet: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var contentViewOutlet: UIView!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

@IBAction func btnBack(_ sender: UIButton) {
    present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
}
```

but as you known, ViewCell has no member dismiss. What i am trying to do is going back to the FirstViewController with this back button in UICollectionViewCell. And yes, app user see this back button in each ui collection records.

Comment: The opposite of show is pop, not dismiss.

Comment: Can we write 'pop' in UICollectionViewCell? If yes, how? Can you write this code like dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest add a callback in `ViewCell` for such small interaction as below,

```
class ViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var lblOutlet: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var contentViewOutlet: UIView!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

public var dismiss: (()-> Void)? = nil

@IBAction func btnBack(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.dismiss?()
}
}
```

Now, in your `ViewController` bind that `callback` inside `cellForItemAt` as,

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell: ViewCell = // Your code to dequeue cell
    cell.dismiss = { [weak self] in
         self?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) // OR Pop whatever
    }
}
```

Comment: Dear @Kamran it says 'Class ViewCell has no initializers' after i add this public var dismiss: (()-> Void)?

Comment: @mannyCalavera You are missing **?** at the end. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

May be you can use protocol & delegate pattern to pop back from second view controller. You can add in your CollectionViewCell file a protocol like

```
protocol popBackDelegate { 
    func popBack()
}
```

then inject it in your CollectionViewCell

```
var popBackDelegate: popBackDelegate!
```

After that you can call it in your btnBack action

```
popBackDelegate.popBack()
```

Now you have to bind it your second view controller's collection view's cellforitem event

```
cell.popBackDelegate = self
```

Lastly you can conform this protocol func in your view controller and pop back in that.

Hopefully I helped you with that.

Comment: since he's presenting the second view controller, it should then "dismiss", not "pop".

Comment: If second and first view controller are in a navigation stack, it should be pop, else (second view controller was presented), should be dismiss. Thanks for your contribution @MumtazHussain

Comment: OP isn't presenting or pushing rather using `show(controller, sender: nil)`. But the actual problem is binding `button` tap to `ViewController` that is covered by the answer. It's up to OP how he want to name the delegate. BTW, in `Swift` `class`, `struct`, `enum`, `protocol`  start with Uppercase letter e.g, `PopBackDelegate`

Comment: Thanks again @Kamran contribution about uppercase letters. You right i missed out that.